# Change TextView of WheelView

Tags: java, android, fonts, textview

I am using [Yuri Kanivets' WheelView](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) in my project.

For translation purposes, I have made a custom TextView with custom Font. The WheelView uses TextView to display text. I would like to use the custom Textview in Wheelview so that it displays the text in custom font. How do I do that?

I don't want to change the original source of wheelview, in case I have to use it for other apps.

Code of the wheelview adapter:

```
/**
* Adapter for string based wheel. Highlights the current value.
*/
private class DateArrayAdapter extends ArrayWheelAdapter<String> {
   // Index of current item
   int currentItem;
   // Index of item to be highlighted
   int currentValue;

   /**
    * Constructor
    */
   public DateArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] items, int current) {
       super(context, items);
       this.currentValue = current;
       setTextSize(16);
   }

   @Override
   protected void configureTextView(TextView view) {
       super.configureTextView(view);
       if (currentItem == currentValue) {
           view.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_blue));
       }
       view.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
       view.setTextSize(18);
   }

   @Override
   public View getItem(int index, View cachedView, ViewGroup parent) {
       currentItem = index;
       return super.getItem(index, cachedView, parent);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a layout xml with your own view. Let us say it is `layout_item.xml`. Set the id of your view (the custom textview) to text using `android:id="@+id/text"`

Use this on your adapter:

```
adapter.setItemResource(R.layout.layout_item);
adapter.setItemTextResource(R.id.text);
```

I guess now it should work

Comment: I tried your solutions, it didn't work. You can take a look at the source code here: http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/trunk/wheel/src/kankan/wheel/widget/adapters/AbstractWheelTextAdapter.java#182

Comment: I ran into another problem. Somehow the code to highlight the current item doesn't work now. Am I missing something?

Comment: it depends on how much have you changed in your customview

Comment: I have just added the above two lines. I think it's because `protected void configureTextView(TextView view)` is expecting a `TextView` object?

Comment: @input no since you are supplying the id of the textview the underlying adapter will get this textview and supply it to configure funtion. weird